# Using a sequence argument to show that $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^3\sin(x)}{x^2+1}$ does not exist

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

> Consider the following the function $f(x)=\frac{x^3\sin(x)}{x^2+1}$. What is the $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^3\sin(x)}{x^2+1}$?

My answer the limit doest not exist because $x_n=n\pi$ goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$ and $f(x_n)=0$  for all $n$ so $f(x_n)$ goes to $0$ as $n\to \infty.$ Also, take $y_n=(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$ goes to $\infty$ as $n\to \infty$ but $f(y_n)=\frac{y_n ^3}{y_n^2+1} (-1)^{n}$. So, $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(y_n)$ does not exist. Thus, $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^3\sin(x)}{x^2+1}$ does not exist.

Is that right? Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Yes it is right!

Comment: Looks good. Just the $y_n$ on their own are sufficient to show that the limit does not exist.

Comment: @copper.hat. What did you mean by $y_n$ sufficient ?

Comment: Meaning you do not need the $x_n$.

Comment: @copper.hat. Yes you are right it would be enough

Comment: @copper.hate even $\frac{x^2 sin(x)}{x^2+1}$ does not exist as well. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your idea is correct. But you want the $y_n = (4n+1)\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ instead. Then $f(y_n) \to \infty$, and $f(x_n) \to 0$ where $x_n = n\pi$.  So  you have $2$ different limits and hence no limit !

Comment: I did show one side the limit is zero and the side Kim it does not exist

Comment: That should be sufficient, but the other side you should have an example that has the limit a number other than $0$. My example is fair enough to demonstrate that point.

Comment: @WangYeFei Don’t you mean $f(y_n)\to\infty$?

Comment: The exponent $3$ looks like a $2$. So, yes you are right, it goes to $\infty$.