# Looking for another way to show limit DNE without using sequence argument

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

I asked a question similar to this yesterday see, [Using a sequence argument to show that $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^3\sin(x)}{x^2+1}$ does not exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4501609/353702). I ask this again since  I could not do it without a sequence argument.

Consider the following the functions $f(x)=\frac{x^2\sin^2(x)}{x^2+1}$ and $g(x)=\frac{x^3\sin^2(x)}{x^2+1}$

What are  the $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x).$ My answer does not exist for both functions. The argument would be similar so I will do just for $f(x).$

Now, $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x^2+1} \frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$. Take $x_n=n\pi$, clearly $x_n\to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$ and $f(x_n)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty.$  Also, take $y_n=(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$. So, $y_n\to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$ and $f(y_n)\to \frac{\pi^2}{4}$ as $n\to\infty.$ So, we have $f(x_n)\neq f(y_n)$. Hence,  $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ does not exist. In case,  $\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x)$, the argument would be quite similar.  Perhaps my questions are

> 1. Is that right?

> 2. Are there other ways to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Let us prove that
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\sin^2(x)$$
does not exist.

Assume that this limit $=L(\in \Bbb R)$.

we have
$$\cos^2(x)=\sin^2(x+\frac{\pi}{2}),$$
$$\sin^2(2x)=\color{red}{4}\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x),$$
and
$$\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$$

So, we will have
$$2L=1$$ and $$1=\color{red}{4}L$$

Comment: I hope my account won't be closed. If not, please delete this answer.

Comment: hamam_ Abdallah. How did you get $1=4L$

Comment: @Gob from the second equality with the red four.

Comment: hamam_abdallah . But this  only shows limit $\sin^2(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: @Gob $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}=1$